# sequelize bulk create recursive process nextTick detected for > 498 records

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize v2.0.0-alpha3 and node.js v0.10.12 . I try to insert > 498 records into my table and my app crashes with the following warning and error:

(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Is there a way to insert >498 records all at once ?

I created a simple test case and found it crashes for > 498 records:

//Models File

```
module.exports = function(sequelize,DataTypes){
 return sequelize.define('insertTest', 
   {
     ID:{
       type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
       autoIncrement:true,
       primaryKey:true,
       get:function(){
         return this.getDataValue('ID');
       },
       set:function(ID){
         return this.setDataValue('ID',ID);
       }
     },
     test:{
       type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
       get:function(){
         return this.getDataValue('test');
       },
       set:function(test){
         return this.setDataValue('test',test);
       }
     }
   },
   {
     timestamps:false,
     tableName: 'insertTest',
     logging:false
   }
 )};
```

//Controller file

```
app.get('/insertTest',function(request,response){
       var value=[];
       var len = parseInt(request.query.len);
       for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
           value.push(i);
       insertTest
       .bulkCreate(value,['test'])
       .success(function(results){response.json('Success');})
       .error(function(error){response.json(error);})
   })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to avoid this error: (node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187065/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-this-error-node-warning-recursive-process-nexttick-d)