# Is there a way to avoid this error: (node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, amazon-s3

I'm seeing a bunch of questions around this error but no one seems to have an actual answer and none of the causes listed by the other posters apply to my case.

I've tracked it down to happening when I upload a particularly large file (50mb or more) from my server over to Amazon's S3.  Somewhere in that process I get several hundred instances of

```
(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.
```

and then eventually a

```
var str = String(f).replace(formatRegExp, function(x) {
                      ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Curious if anyone else has seen this specific instance and managed to find a solution. I'll obviously post one as an answer if I figure it out.

Comment: maybe if you posted some of the code that was doing the upload...

Comment: As this is a problem requiring fixing the broken code, you'll need to post exactly which modules you are using at which version and if you are able to track down a stack trace, that trace and your first party code that is triggering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually fix this you must

1. Identify the line of code that is causing this.

   - search for `process.nextTick` in both your code and your npm dependencies
   - OR If you can reproduce in the debugger and set a break point at the code in node core that throws that error, you may be able to look at the stack at that point and identify the root cause file/line.
2. Change that code to use `setImmediate` instead

   - It is not necessarily your app code that is the root cause, so you may need to fork/PR a third party module